# Observable Lifecycle Management - How to make data stream from input axis?

Tags: unity-game-engine, reactive-programming, reactive

Unity 5.4.3f1.

I am learning reactive programming using UniRx to target Unity.
A the moment I am trying to create a simple data stream from input axis.

```
   public IObservable<float> Movement;

void Start () 
{
    this.Movement = Observable.EveryUpdate()
                    .Select(_ => Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") )
                    .Subscribe(f => Debug.Log(f))
                    .AddTo(this);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.IDisposable' to `UniRx.IObservable<float>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266) (Assembly-CSharp)
```

The example from UniRx compiles fine.

```
    Observable.IntervalFrame(30).Subscribe(x => Debug.Log(x)).AddTo(this);
```

I do not see much difference between the two. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Well I am stupid. Creation of observable and subscription should be two different things. Code compiles fine when they are separate.

```
public IObservable<float> Movement;

void Start () 
{
    this.Movement = Observable.EveryUpdate()
        .Select(_ => Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") )
        .Where( f => f > 0.01f || f < -0.01f);

    this.Movement.Subscribe(f => Debug.Log(f))
        .AddTo(this);
}
```